# Startup script for gnome-terminal doesn't change tab title nor executes commands

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, manjaro

I'd like to automate the setup of my dev environment. I had to fallback from guake to gnome-terminal since guake (dropdown behavior was incredible) has issues with Wayland. I'm on Manjaro with gnome desktop.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR VIM" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -- vim
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR CMD" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -e 'git status'
gnome-terminal --tab -t "TSR Server" --working-directory /my/working/dir/ -e 'bundle exec hanami server'
```

This does the following:

1. command: works in full. A new tab is opened, title renamed and vim is started.
2. command: it runs git status but it stays in that state. I can't run any other commands after that. Also, the title is not renamed. The working directory is set.
3. command: same as the second. If I stop the server with CRTL + C, I cant use the tab anymore.

I'm also prompted to change **-e** to **--** for the 2. and 3. command. However, doing that returns another error: Failed to execve: File or directory with that name doesn't exist.

Finally, the initial tab remains opened.

I checked other SO questions and tried my google fu and implementing different solutions, however, I had no success.

Can someone help with this problem?

Best, seba

Comment: This is probably better suited at https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com